# Dynamically add files to the FileReferenceList class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I was wondering that if there is way to add/select files to filerefernce instead of using filereference.browse().

Usage: I have to pick all files from a directory to be uploaded.

Thanks 
Siddharth

Edit: Or is there any other way of uploading all files in a directory (num of files not more than 25)

Comment: Do you see a privacy issue here?

Comment: @MartyWallace You are right about the Privacy issue. But, in your own application, if I want to provide sync all files type facility, how would you achieve it.

Comment: You can't - you have to ask for the user's permission and have them select the files (even if you're the user).

Answer (score 1):

You must use FileReferenceList.browse() method.
Flash Player creates an array of selected files called FileReferenceList.fileList